# Count array items and add div after certain number

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
$specs = array ('Name' => 'Cleopatra', 'Year' => '2008', 'Length' => '20ft', 'Make' => 'manufacturer', 'Model' => 'model', 'Engines Count' => '2', 'Fuel' => 'Diesel', 'Rudder' => 'rudder', 'Keel' => 'keel', 'Price' => '$1'); 

foreach ($specs as $label => $detail) {
  echo "<tr>";  
  echo "<th>{$label}</th>";
  echo "<td>{$detail}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

The foreach loop returns 1 column in each row. How can I render 4 columns per row like so

```
   <tr>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
      <th>Label</th>
      <td>Detail</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: 4 rows per column? or columns per row? Your example is columns per row.

Answer (score 5):

Just add counter, something like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($specs as $label => $detail) {
  if($i%4 == 0 && $i != 0) { 
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
  }
  echo "<th>{$label}</th>";
  echo "<td>{$detail}</td>";
  $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Update: Fixed edge case `$i=0` and `<tr>`'s in right order

Comment: Not quite, this doesn't put the `<tr>`s and `</tr>`s in the right spot.

Comment: Thanks, fixed, hope now it's okay

Answer (score 1):

Set a counter, and every 4th iteration, print a new `<tr>`.

```
$i = 0;
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($specs as $label => $detail) {
  if($i !== 0 && $i%4 === 0){
     echo '</tr><tr>';
  }
  echo "<th>{$label}</th>";
  echo "<td>{$detail}</td>";
  $i++;
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remember your maths from school, you can use the [mod operator](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) to get the remainder of a division operation.  This is what you need to get what you want.

```
 echo "<tr>"; 
foreach ($specs as $label => $detail) 
{
  $counter++;
  //get remainder of division by 4, when 1 create new row
 if ($counter % 4 == 1)
 {
  echo "</tr>"; 
  echo "<tr>"; 
 }
 echo "<th>{$label}</th>";
 echo "<td>{$detail}</td>";


}   
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This carries the assumption that your index is zero based.

First we define the number of columns we want in each row. Then, we define two rules sets: when to start a new row and when to end a row.

We want to start a new row on the first iteration and anytime the current iteration count is divisible by the number of columns we want in each row.

We want to end a row when we are on the last iteration. Also we will end a row anytime that we are not on the first iteration and the total count of the collection minus the current iteration count is divisible by the number of columns we want in each row minus one.

```
$cols_in_row = 5;
foreach ($array as $i => $item)
{
    if ($i == 0 || $i % $cols_in_row == 0)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    echo '<td>'.$item.'</td>';

    if ($i + 1 == count($array) || ($i != 0 && count($array) - $i % ($cols_in_row - 1)))
    {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

This method allows you to only write the opening and closing tags once so that editors don't think that you are forgetting to open or close something.